# Is it proper to wish 'Halloween', 'Good Friday' and the like (if any)?

Tags: word-usage

We generally wish people on festival putting a simple-yet-convincing word *happy*. Surprisingly, in India, anything can be wished putting 'happy' before any word that brings a holiday in your office ;)

The question came to my mind when today I heard *Happy Good Friday* by a non-native speaker. I am more *shocked* than surprised. I'm pretty sure *happy* does not go with any such day/celebration(?)/event.

Though I read Wikipedia for both those days I'm not sure whether it's a celebration or showing our condolence to those respected personalities. Also, though there's *good (adj)* in *Good Friday (noun phrase)* it was the day of grief, wasn't it? I cannot say *Happy [Good Friday].*

Is it proper to wish Halloween or Good Friday? If yes, I'm not sure using *happy* there. And yes, my dear **native speakers** are most welcomed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it depends on the type of event/celebration:

- *"Happy Christmas/Thanksgiving"* is used because traditionally we meet up with our families (which is supposed to be a happy thing), etc etc (plus Christmas is a happy religious holiday)
- *"Happy Halloween"* is acceptable, because for children it's full of candy, dressing up, etc
- *"Happy Good Friday"* doesn't make sense, because Good Friday is a religious holiday full of penitence, fasting and so on, as it's in remembrance of the day Jesus Christ died on the cross); as such, wishing somebody a happy Good Friday would, at best, just sound weird, and at worst be utterly blasphemous
- *"Happy Easter"*, conversely, does make sense, because while it is a religious holiday and it is naturally closely linked to Good Friday, it's in remembrance of the day Jesus Christ rose from the dead - that is, a happy occasion.

Comment: (A separate question is why "Good Friday" is called "Good" in the first place, especially since it's not the case in many other languages...)

Comment: That's what I initially thought! But then added Halloween to cover as many events as possible. But thanks for this input as it provoked me to put that question.