# Does the adjective 'good' justifies its meaning in 'Good Friday'?

Tags: word-choice

I'm putting this as a separate question though I already asked it [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21543/is-it-proper-to-wish-halloween-good-friday-and-the-like-if-any). That's because either I will learn more about using the *adjective good* or I'll know more about how a phrasal noun which refers to some grief takes a positive adjective?

What is *good* in Good Friday? An adjective, isn't it? But then if it's really good, how does it justify its meaning? As Good Friday is certainly *a very sad day* to lose such a person of God. Where's the goodness in that? Is there any positive adjective that's used this way forming a noun-phrase which actually means exactly opposite to that (A bad Friday?, indeed a bad day as we lost him). I'm choosing the tag 'Word Choice' here.

Comment: This is etymology.  *Good Friday* isn't understood as "a Friday that is good", and most people who use the phrase have no idea where the "good" part came from.

Comment: @snailplane I see. I really wonder where is the 'goodness' in that Friday. In that sense, I'm more convinced with 'Black Friday'. Helix answer is nice as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [the origin of Good Friday is  contested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Friday#Etymology), the phrase can mean *Holy Friday*.

- Etymology of "Good Friday"

  > <sub>[From Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Good-Friday?q=good%20friday)</sub>
  >
  > from good, in the sense *'holy, observed as a holy day'*.
- "Good" can mean Holy.

  > <sub>[From Wiktionary; sense 5](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/good#Adjective)</sub>
  >
  > *(especially when capitalized)* Holy.

<sub>For a religious answer: [the same question on Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14286/why-is-good-friday-called-good).</sub>

Comment: Oh, I din' think of it. Thanks. It's really a good one!

Answer (score 0):

I had always been perplexed as to why the day commemorating the worst day in recorded history would be qualified as good. But synonyms of good are virtuous, righteous, or commendable. Good Friday is the day Christ submitted to the will of God to be crucified. So, good refers to the virtues of Christ, not the day. Still, I think the Holiday should be renamed.